# I can't login to kde

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kde, login-manager

I have an ArchLinux with XFCE4 and lightdm.
I want to use KDE.
I install the kde and plasma and SDDM.

```
$ sudo pacman -S plasma kde-applications sddm xorg-server xorg-apps xorg
$ sudo systemctl enable sddm
startx
```

But: I can't login to kde. If I enter my username and password, the computer will be crashes. Even if I use lightdm.
Now I can't login to my XFCE with a regular user. And I should to login as root.
and if I run my plasma I can see my xfce without background.
How can I login to KDE?

Comment: Welcome, by "can't login" what exactly do you mean? Doesn't accept your user/password? something else? **[edit]** the question adding this information, don't do it in the comments.

Comment: Do you not get a GUI? What is the output of the `startx` command?

Comment: And @lanHunter if I enter the startx command my computer  crashes.

Comment: How it crashes ? Give error output in question.

Comment: @Moheb **Please** add the valuable information in the question, **[edit]** it, so no further comment are needed to specify what the problem is.

Comment: What that even mean plasma starts.... XFCE?  Please add screenshot.

Comment: So you are in. No more problem.

Comment: No, It's my xfce. It's not my kde.

Comment: Hello! Now I know the question's answer. 
KDE is written with QT and XFCE is written with GTK. 
I don't know why but I know we can't install KDE with XFCE.